# Jetpack Compose: is it possible to have multiple canvases in one page?

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

Can I stack multiple canvases in a column? In the example below, each DeviceView has a canvas inside.

```
Column() {
 DeviceView(PVSUM)
 DeviceView(PVSUM)
}
```

Asking, because it doesn't seem to work. Only one canvas is shown.

Also tried to draw each with a different offset.

```
Column() {
    DeviceView(x1,y1, PVSUM)
    DeviceView(x2,y2, PVSUM)
}
```

But only the first DeviceView is shown.

Comment: It should work. Post DeviceView code.

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for asking. Found 
```
Canvas(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
````
which explains, why the first takes all space.